# Features in sklearn logistic regression

Tags: logistic, python, logit, scikit-learn, natural-language

I have some problem with adding own features to `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`. 
But anyway lets see some example code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# Numbers are class of tag
resultsNER = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# Acording to resultNER every row is another class so is another features
# but in this way every row have the same features
xNER = np.array([[1.,0.,0.,0.,-1.,1.],
                 [1.,0.,1.,0., 0.,1.],
                 [1.,1.,1.,1., 1.,1.],
                 [0.,0.,0.,0., 0.,0.],
                 [1.,1.,1.,0., 0.,0.]])

# Assing resultsNER to y
y = resultsNER
# Create LogReg
logit = LogisticRegression(C = 1.0)
# Learn LogReg
logit.fit(xNER, y)

# Some test vector to check wich class will be predict
xPP = np.array([1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,1.])

# linear = LinearRegression()
# linear.fit(x, y)

print "expected: ", y
print "predicted:", logit.predict(xPP)
print "decision: ", logit.decision_function(xNER)
print logit.coef_
# print linear.predict(x)
print "params: ", logit.get_params(deep=True)
```

Code above is clear and easy. So I have some classes which I called `1,2,3,4,5(resultsNER)` they are according to some classes like `data`, `person`, `organization` etc. So for each class I make own features which return true or false in this case `1` and `0`.

Example: 
If token equals "(S|s)unday" is data class. In mathematical way is clear. I have token for each class features I test it. Then I look which class have the max value of sum of features (that’s why return number not boolean) and pick it up. 
In other words: I use `argmax` function. 
Of course in summary each feature has alpha coefficients. In this case is multi class classification so I need know how add multi class features to `sklearn.LogisticRegression`.

I need two things alpha coefficients and how add my own features to Logistic Regression. The most important for me is how add to `sklearn.LogisticRegression` my own features functions for each class. 
I know I can compute coefficients by gradient descent. But I think when I use `fit(x,y)` the `LogisticRegression` use some algorithm to compute coefficients which I can get by attribute
`.coef_` .

So in the end my main question is:

**How to add own features for different classes in my example class `1,2,3,4,5(resultNER)`?**